# Verifying SHA256 Hash from MySQL Database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, hash, sha256

I have created a program that is set up with a remote MySQL database. The database stores the login information for this program and the passwords are hashed using SHA256. If the user enters the correct information in the login form then they will proceed to the GUI.

My problem is verifying the hash on the user-end of things. How would I got about this? Most tutorials I have read are too over-explained and leave me confused.

Here is the code for my login button.

```
        try
        {
            string strConnect = "Server=***;Port=***;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnect);
            MySqlCommand selectCmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from ***.*** where username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' ;", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            int count = 0;
            myReader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                this.Close(); form2.Show();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Theres 2 Users with that username Please contact administrator ...Access Denied");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is Not correct .. Please try Again!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to hash what the user typed in exactly the same way that you hashed the password when you stored it. Then, if the hashed password from the database matches the hashed password that the user just typed in, they typed the correct password.

Usually there is a random salt involved so if multiple people use the password "password" the hashed password won't look the same in the database. That has nothing to do with your current question, but should definitely be something you look into before you consider your "storing passwords" solution complete.

Here's an example of some code you might use:

```
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(userTypedPassword);
//
// This is where you'd normally append or prepend the salt bytes
//
var hasher = System.Security.CryptographySHA256.Create();
byte[] hashedBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
```

Now it depends on how the hash is stored in the database, if it's just binary data you can compare the byte arrays. If it's stored as a base64 string, you can convert the bytes:

```
var hashedString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
```

...and then do a string comparison between the stored string and `hashedString`.

Comment: I somewhat understand this, I have this as `var hashedPW = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create(txtPassword.Text);` then modified the command string as such `MySqlCommand selectCmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from ***.*** where username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + hashedPW + "' ;", myConn);`

Comment: @TobyCook How is the hash stored in the database? As binary data or a base64 string?

Comment: @TobyCook Also, look again at my code. You don't want to pass the password to the `Create()` method. That's for an entirely different thing.

Comment: the password is stored as varchar(64). How would I compare the text entered into the textbox to the value of the password on the server?

Comment: @TobyCook Well, all you need is the password field from the record with the matching username. Something like `var stored = myReader["password"].ToString();`. Then just do `if (hashedString == stored)`

Comment: I've have an issue with this. I used the SHA256 hash method on a pass string in C#, and then I pulled a plain text password string from the mysql db using sha2(user_password, 256), and when I compare them, they don't match. I tried converting the bytes on the C# to hex, and using ToBase64String(), neither match. Any suggestions?